# passing hidden value ajax to servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets, servlet-3.0

I am trying to pass data ajax to servlet. My html has 3 clickable list item and with click, I want to pass the text of that element. I have no trouble with reaching to clicked element and getting text of it but my servlet is not getting the value.

my script,

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 // Example document-ready block
 $(function() {
  // Your event
  $('li').click(function() {
   // Get the ID for the element that was clicked
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var f = document.getElementById('clicked');
   f.value = id;
   //alert(id);

   $.ajax({
    url : 'GetPhone',
    data : {id : id},
    type : 'get',
    success : function(data) {
     //alert(id);
    },
    error : function() {
     alert('error');
    }
   }); 
  });
 });
</script>
```

my doGet() in servlet,

```
System.out.println("Servlet called!!");
String text = "Update successful";
String name = request.getParameter("clickedFeature");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println(name + " " + text);
```

and lastly, important part from html,

```html
<FORM ACTION="GetPhone" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" id="clicked" name="clickedFeature">
</FORM>
```

Comment: You are passing data : {id : id} then the variable name is id which is to be fetched at your server side.

Comment: thanks, ı changed it but it still not work @MayankPandey